# Сделать движение кораблика в обе стороны?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно, что бы караблик двигался в обе стороны, при этом проходя все пункты.
Например из *1* пункта в *4* ( 1-2-3-4 ), или в другую сторону из *4* в *1* ( 4-3-2-1 ).
Не ругайтесь на js мало того, что он на jquery, так еще и костыльно написан, просто я в отчаянии.

Спасибо всем кто уделит внимание.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Код рабочий, но такой костыльный, да еще и работает только в одну сторону
  var ship = $('.history-ship-svg')
  defaultTime = 500;
  dataShip = ship.dataset;

  function circle2() {
    ship.css('transform', 'translate(164px, 14px)');
    ship.attr('data-position', 'circle-2');
  }

  function circle3() {
    ship.css('transform', 'translate(294px, -35px)');
    ship.attr('data-position', 'circle-3');
  }

  function circle4() {
    ship.css('transform', 'translate(415px, -109px)');
    ship.attr('data-position', 'circle-4');
  }

  function circle5() {
    ship.css('transform', 'translate(548px, -113px)');
    ship.attr('data-position', 'circle-5');
  }

  function circle6() {
    ship.css('transform', 'translate(670px, -94px)');
    ship.attr('data-position', 'circle-6');
  }

  function circle7() {
    ship.css('transform', 'translate(793px, -180px)');
    ship.attr('data-position', 'circle-7');
  }

  function circle8() {
    ship.css('transform', 'translate(885px, -237px)');
    ship.attr('data-position', 'circle-8');
  }



  $('.circle-1').click(function() {
    ship.css('transform', 'translate(0,0)')
  });

  $('.circle-2').click(function() {
    circle2();
  });

  $('.circle-3').click(function() {
    circle2();
    setTimeout(function() {
      circle3();
    }, defaultTime);
  });

  $('.circle-4').click(function() {
    circle2();
    setTimeout(function() {
      circle3();
    }, defaultTime);
    setTimeout(function() {
      circle4();
    }, defaultTime * 2);
  });

  $('.circle-5').click(function() {
    circle2();
    setTimeout(function() {
      circle3();
    }, defaultTime);
    setTimeout(function() {
      circle4();
    }, defaultTime * 2);
    setTimeout(function() {
      circle5();
    }, defaultTime * 2 + defaultTime);
  });

  $('.circle-6').click(function() {
    circle2();
    setTimeout(function() {
      circle3();
    }, defaultTime);
    setTimeout(function() {
      circle4();
    }, defaultTime * 2);
    setTimeout(function() {
      circle5();
    }, defaultTime * 2 + defaultTime);
    setTimeout(function() {
      circle6();
    }, defaultTime * 4);
  });

  $('.circle-7').click(function() {
    circle2();
    setTimeout(function() {
      circle3();
    }, defaultTime);
    setTimeout(function() {
      circle4();
    }, defaultTime * 2);
    setTimeout(function() {
      circle5();
    }, defaultTime * 2 + defaultTime);
    setTimeout(function() {
      circle6();
    }, defaultTime * 4);
    setTimeout(function() {
      circle7();
    }, defaultTime * 4 + defaultTime);
  });

  $('.circle-8').click(function() {
    circle2();
    setTimeout(function() {
      circle3();
    }, defaultTime);
    setTimeout(function() {
      circle4();
    }, defaultTime * 2);
    setTimeout(function() {
      circle5();
    }, defaultTime * 2 + defaultTime);
    setTimeout(function() {
      circle6();
    }, defaultTime * 4);
    setTimeout(function() {
      circle7();
    }, defaultTime * 4 + defaultTime);
    setTimeout(function() {
      circle8();
    }, defaultTime * 6);

  });

  var data = document.querySelector('.history-ship-svg').dataset;
  if (data.position == "circle-8") {
    $('.circle-7').click(function() {
      circle7();
      dead;
    });
  }





});
```

```css
@import url 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans';
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #444;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.limiter {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main-content {
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.mission {
  width: 75%;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.mission-title {
  color: #eb4f47;
}

.history-content {
  width: 75%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #deedf4;
}

.history-content-date {
  color: #49a2c7;
}

.history-ship {
  position: relative;
}

.circle {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='22px' height='22px' viewBox='0 0 22 22'><circle cx='11.00' cy='11.00' r='11.00' fill='#49a2c7'/></svg>") no-repeat;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
}

.circle:hover span {
  color: #f8f8f8;
  background-color: #eb4f47;
}

.circle-1 {
  top: 252px;
  left: 224px;
}

.circle-2 {
  top: 269px;
  left: 388px;
}

.circle-3 {
  top: 231px;
  left: 520px;
}

.circle-4 {
  top: 147px;
  left: 637px;
}

.circle-5 {
  top: 142px;
  left: 773px;
}

.circle-6 {
  top: 163px;
  left: 897px;
}

.circle-7 {
  top: 82px;
  left: 1019px;
}

.circle-8 {
  top: 17px;
  left: 1111px;
}

div[class*='circle-'] {
  position: absolute;
}

div[class*='circle-'] span {
  position: relative;
  top: 26px;
  right: 5px;
  padding: 2px 3px;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.history-ship-svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 210px;
  left: 207px;
  width: 63px;
  height: 41px;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' width='63px' height='41px' viewBox='0 0 63 41'><g transform='matrix(0.17 0.03 -0.02 0.17 1.46 -14.92)'><g><path fillRule='evenodd' d='M 94 281C 94 281 305 281 305 281 305 281 198 228 198 228 198 228 94 281 94 281Z' fill='rgb(61,159,133)'/><path fillRule='evenodd' d='M 17 149C 17 149 94 281 94 281 94 281 198 228 198 228 198 228 17 149 17 149Z' fill='rgb(79,205,171)'/><path fillRule='evenodd' d='M 197 228C 197 228 380 150 380 150 380 150 305 281 305 281 305 281 197 228 197 228Z' fill='rgb(79,205,171)'/><path fillRule='evenodd' d='M 130 198C 130 198 192 111 192 111 192 111 198 228 198 228 198 228 130 198 130 198Z' fill='rgb(121,227,197)'/><path fillRule='evenodd' d='M 192 111C 192 111 198 228 198 228 198 228 267 199 267 199 267 199 192 111 192 111Z' fill='rgb(121,226,198)'/><path fillRule='evenodd' d='M 249 178C 249 178 383 149 383 149 383 149 267 199 267 199 267 199 249 178 249 178Z' fill='rgb(61,159,133)'/><path fillRule='evenodd' d='M 17 149C 17 149 147 174 147 174 147 174 131 199 131 199 131 199 17 149 17 149Z' fill='rgb(61,159,133)'/><path fillRule='evenodd' d='M 193 226C 193 226 198 229 198 229 198 229 203 226 203 226 203 226 192 112 192 112 192 112 193 226 193 226Z' fill='rgb(79,205,171)'/><path fillRule='evenodd' d='M 191 89C 191 89 191 114 191 114 191 114 193 114 193 114 193 114 193 89 193 89 193 89 191 89 191 89Z' fill='rgb(121,227,197)'/><path fillRule='evenodd' d='M 193 65C 193 65 193 103 193 103 193 103 139 85 139 85 139 85 193 65 193 65Z' fill='rgb(219,71,69)'/></g></g></svg>") no-repeat;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s linear;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s linear;
  transition: transform 0.5s linear;
  transition: transform 0.5s linear, -webkit-transform 0.5s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>

<main class="main-content">
  <div class="limiter">
    <div class="mission">
      <h3 class="mission-title">Наша миссия</h3>
      <p class="mission-paragraph"> ВЛБАНК (ОАО) перешёл на промышленную эксплуатацию автоматизированной банковской системы ЦФТ-Банк, современного масштабируемого решения, позволившего банку перестроить свой технологический цикл и расширить потенциальные возможности для развития.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="history-ship">
    <div class="history-ship-svg" data-position="circle-1"></div>
    <div class="circle circle-1"><span>2013</span></div>
    <div class="circle circle-2"><span>2002</span></div>
    <div class="circle circle-3"><span>2006</span></div>
    <div class="circle circle-4"><span>2012</span></div>
    <div class="circle circle-5"><span>2010</span></div>
    <div class="circle circle-6"><span>2006</span></div>
    <div class="circle circle-7"><span>1990</span></div>
    <div class="circle circle-8"><span>2013</span></div>
    <svg width="1305" height="372" viewbox="0 0 1305 372">
      <image x="0" y="0" xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/7j542v3.png"></image>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="limiter">
    <div class="history-content">
      <div class="history-content-for-circle-1">
        <h3 class="history-content-title">Расширение возможностей</h3><span class="history-content-date">24 августа 2013 г.</span>
        <p class="history-content-paragraph">ВЛБАНК (ОАО) перешёл на промышленную эксплуатацию автоматизированной банковской системы ЦФТ-Банк, современного масштабируемого решения, позволившего банку перестроить свой технологический цикл и расширить потенциальные возможности для развития.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--
    .history-content-for-circle-2
     h3.history-content-title Расширение возможностей
     span.history-content-date 24 августа 2002 г.
     p.history-content-paragraph.
      ВЛБАНК (ОАО) перешёл на промышленную эксплуатацию автоматизированной банковской системы ЦФТ-Банк, современного масштабируемого решения, позволившего банку перестроить свой  технологический цикл и расширить потенциальные возможности для развития.
    -->
  </div>
</main>
```

[<sub>http://su0.ru/WM6V</sub>](http://su0.ru/WM6V)

Comment: код в вопросе опубликуйте

Comment: извините, добавил

Answer (score 4):

```js
$(function() {
  var ship = $(".history-ship-svg"),
    circles = $(".circle"),
    pos = [],
    index = 0,
    x = -17,
    y = -45;
  circles.on("click", function() {
    var num = circles.index(this);
    for (; num != index;) {
      index < num ? index++ : index--;
      pos.push(circles[index])
    }
    pos.length && move()
  });

  function move() {
    if (!pos.length) return;
    var elem = pos.shift();
    var loc = $(elem).position();
    var left = loc.left + x;
    var top = loc.top + y;
    ship.stop().animate({
      left: left + "px",
      top: top + "px"
    }, 800, move)
  }
});
```

```css
@import url 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans';
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #444;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.limiter {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main-content {
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.mission {
  width: 75%;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.mission-title {
  color: #eb4f47;
}

.history-content {
  width: 75%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #deedf4;
}

.history-content-date {
  color: #49a2c7;
}

.history-ship {
  position: relative;
}

.circle {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='22px' height='22px' viewBox='0 0 22 22'><circle cx='11.00' cy='11.00' r='11.00' fill='#49a2c7'/></svg>") no-repeat;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
}

.circle:hover span {
  color: #f8f8f8;
  background-color: #eb4f47;
}

.circle-1 {
  top: 252px;
  left: 224px;
}

.circle-2 {
  top: 269px;
  left: 388px;
}

.circle-3 {
  top: 231px;
  left: 520px;
}

.circle-4 {
  top: 147px;
  left: 637px;
}

.circle-5 {
  top: 142px;
  left: 773px;
}

.circle-6 {
  top: 163px;
  left: 897px;
}

.circle-7 {
  top: 82px;
  left: 1019px;
}

.circle-8 {
  top: 17px;
  left: 1111px;
}

div[class*='circle-'] {
  position: absolute;
}

div[class*='circle-'] span {
  position: relative;
  top: 26px;
  right: 5px;
  padding: 2px 3px;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.history-ship-svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 210px;
  left: 207px;
  width: 63px;
  height: 41px;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' width='63px' height='41px' viewBox='0 0 63 41'><g transform='matrix(0.17 0.03 -0.02 0.17 1.46 -14.92)'><g><path fillRule='evenodd' d='M 94 281C 94 281 305 281 305 281 305 281 198 228 198 228 198 228 94 281 94 281Z' fill='rgb(61,159,133)'/><path fillRule='evenodd' d='M 17 149C 17 149 94 281 94 281 94 281 198 228 198 228 198 228 17 149 17 149Z' fill='rgb(79,205,171)'/><path fillRule='evenodd' d='M 197 228C 197 228 380 150 380 150 380 150 305 281 305 281 305 281 197 228 197 228Z' fill='rgb(79,205,171)'/><path fillRule='evenodd' d='M 130 198C 130 198 192 111 192 111 192 111 198 228 198 228 198 228 130 198 130 198Z' fill='rgb(121,227,197)'/><path fillRule='evenodd' d='M 192 111C 192 111 198 228 198 228 198 228 267 199 267 199 267 199 192 111 192 111Z' fill='rgb(121,226,198)'/><path fillRule='evenodd' d='M 249 178C 249 178 383 149 383 149 383 149 267 199 267 199 267 199 249 178 249 178Z' fill='rgb(61,159,133)'/><path fillRule='evenodd' d='M 17 149C 17 149 147 174 147 174 147 174 131 199 131 199 131 199 17 149 17 149Z' fill='rgb(61,159,133)'/><path fillRule='evenodd' d='M 193 226C 193 226 198 229 198 229 198 229 203 226 203 226 203 226 192 112 192 112 192 112 193 226 193 226Z' fill='rgb(79,205,171)'/><path fillRule='evenodd' d='M 191 89C 191 89 191 114 191 114 191 114 193 114 193 114 193 114 193 89 193 89 193 89 191 89 191 89Z' fill='rgb(121,227,197)'/><path fillRule='evenodd' d='M 193 65C 193 65 193 103 193 103 193 103 139 85 139 85 139 85 193 65 193 65Z' fill='rgb(219,71,69)'/></g></g></svg>") no-repeat;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-30deg);
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
  -webkit-animation: spin 3.2s ease-in-out infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin 3.2s ease-in-out infinite;
  -o-animation: spin 3.2s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: spin 3.2s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(15deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(15deg);
    transform: rotate(15deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(15deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(15deg);
    transform: rotate(15deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main class="main-content">
  <div class="limiter">
    <div class="mission">
      <h3 class="mission-title">Наша миссия</h3>
      <p class="mission-paragraph"> ВЛБАНК (ОАО) перешёл на промышленную эксплуатацию автоматизированной банковской системы ЦФТ-Банк, современного масштабируемого решения, позволившего банку перестроить свой технологический цикл и расширить потенциальные возможности для развития.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="history-ship">
    <div class="history-ship-svg" data-position="circle-1"></div>
    <div class="circle circle-1"><span>2013</span></div>
    <div class="circle circle-2"><span>2002</span></div>
    <div class="circle circle-3"><span>2006</span></div>
    <div class="circle circle-4"><span>2012</span></div>
    <div class="circle circle-5"><span>2010</span></div>
    <div class="circle circle-6"><span>2006</span></div>
    <div class="circle circle-7"><span>1990</span></div>
    <div class="circle circle-8"><span>2013</span></div>
    <svg width="1305" height="372" viewbox="0 0 1305 372">
      <image x="0" y="0" xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/7j542v3.png"></image>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="limiter">
    <div class="history-content">
      <div class="history-content-for-circle-1">
        <h3 class="history-content-title">Расширение возможностей</h3><span class="history-content-date">24 августа 2013 г.</span>
        <p class="history-content-paragraph">ВЛБАНК (ОАО) перешёл на промышленную эксплуатацию автоматизированной банковской системы ЦФТ-Банк, современного масштабируемого решения, позволившего банку перестроить свой технологический цикл и расширить потенциальные возможности для развития.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Господи дай тебе здоровья!!!!